# Flex 3 skinning the Datatip of a hslider component

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, tooltip, slider, skinning

Does anybody know how to skin the datatip of a hslider component.

I have created a 3 skins with degrafa. One for the track, one for thumb and one for the datatip. I had no problem attaching the skins for the track and thumb of the hslider component. But how can i skin the datatip?

Does anybody know?

DJ

Comment: please post somewhere a sources and let us know, so we will show your where to apply

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use [this](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Styling_the_data_tip_on_a_Spark_HSlider_control_in-14627.html) manual, but its better to do on your own sample.

Comment: Thanks for reply Eugene,
I have seen the example. But that is Flex 4 related. Unfortunatly i working with the flex 3 sdk. Do you know how i can skin the datatip on the Hslider component? Do i have to override some classes?

Comment: look here http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/11/customing-the-flex-hslider-and-vslider-controls/ and once again post your sources, especially if you need for old flex3

Comment: Thanks Eugene, 
But i don´t want to style the datatip but i would like to skin it.
Anyways.
thanks for your reply

DJ

Comment: @DJ please share the current code, so I could help you, i don't want to write whole skining for sucks old MX, but I could advise you where to place code of dataTip instead. You choose.